# UncaughtReferenceError : foo is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am manipulating the json array in the `jquery.Ajax` function. The syntax got me very confused so I am not able to find this error. What I am doing I have bind the click function to the anchor tag and then when I hit that anchor tag and called the foo() function this error showed up  `UncaughtReferenceError : foo is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick`

```
  function show(thelink)
{

    var cat = thelink.innerHTML;
    var productContainer = document.getElementById("productContainer");

    $.ajax({

           type:"POST",
           url:"fetchdata1",
           data:"cat="+cat,

         success:function(data){
            productContainer.innerHTML ="";
            var $productContainer = $('#productContainer');
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
              if(value['newVar'] === 1)
              {
              $productContainer.append("<div id='productBox' class='grid_3'>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><img src='"+value["image"]+"'/></a><br/>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><span class='black'>"+value['name']+"</span></a><br/>\n\
             <span class='black'>By "+value['company']+"</span><br/><span class='red'>RS."+value['price']+"</span>\n\
             <br/><br/><a href='#' onclick='foo(this)' pid='"+value['id']+"'>REMOVE</a></div>");

             }  
             else{

             $productContainer.append("<div id='productBox' class='grid_3'>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><img src='"+value["image"]+"'/></a><br/>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><span class='black'>"+value['name']+"</span></a><br/>\n\
             <span class='black'>By "+value['company']+"</span><br/><span class='red'>RS."+value['price']+"</span></div>"); 
             }
        }) ;

     }      

    });


     function foo(obj){

            var pid = $(obj).attr("pid");
            $(obj).bind("click", function(){

                    $.ajax({

                      type:"POST",
                      url:"removeFromWishlist",
                      data:"pid="+pid,

                      success:function(response){

                      }


                    });



            });

    }  


    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where you are using `onclick='foo(this)'` in your HTML and you did not defined function `foo`.

Comment: I have defined it below

Comment: Please see the explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you have defined function `foo` inside `show` function, so it will only be accessible from `show` scope.

So when you use `onclick='foo(this)'` in your HTML, you are referring a `foo`function in the `window` global scope so that's why you got:

> UncaughtReferenceError : foo is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

You need to move function `foo` declaration outside of `show` function, so it can be accessible from `window` global scope.

Comment: one more thing click function is not working smoothly  I have to click it twice or thrice only then ajax request is made to the server.

Comment: actually I have to click the anchor tag twice to make the ajax request. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @sony I think it's something in relation with synchronous call, because you are making two ajax call.